# Python Jupyter notebook: run via shell script (Ubuntu 16.04.4) (i.e. with nbconvert)

Tags: python, shell, jupyter-notebook, batch-processing, remote-server

I am using a remote server and would like to run a few jupyter notebooks in the background such that when log out the job still runs and also making use of the 36 cpu cores I am paying for.

So far I have the building blocks but would need help to synthesize them:

1. nohup: usually when I run a python notebook in "background" I use `nohup jupyter notebook`. After that I just execute every single cell in the notebook, close it and close my terminal
2. nbconvert: `jupyter nbconvert --to python <YourNotebook>.ipynb` would allow to run a jupyter notebook from the command line.
3. shell script: via the WRDS "batch job" function I know that, i.e. I can run a script as follows:

   `#!/bin/bash`

   `#$ -cwd`

   `#$ -m abe`

   `#$ -M myemail@myunisversity.ch`

   `echo "Starting Job at date"`

   `sas myscript.sas`

   `echo "Ending Job at date"`

And for instance, WRDS allows to run 5 batch jobs per user.

Let's say I have:

1. Notebook_1.ipynb
2. Notebook_2.ipynb
3. Notebook_3.ipynb

How could I combine the three "building blocks" above to make my Notebook_1, Notebook_2 and Notebook_3 running as python scripts in the background as separate jobs (each making use a cpu core)?

Can you show me an example script (especially when I use a virtualenv)?